# Why did restarting the Application Pool fix our failed login System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException?

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We were receiving the following error, about a failed login. Recycling the application, pool by making an meaningless change to the web.config, fixed the error, and we could subsequently log in. The error may (or may not) have started after restoring the database from a backup. In any case, why would restarting the application pool fix the login failure?

```
2014-08-27 21:17:48,477 [10] Orchard.Tasks.BackgroundService - Error while processing background task    
NHibernate.TransactionException: Begin failed with SQL exception --->     
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "some_database_name" requested by the login. The login failed.    
Login failed for user 'some_database_user'.    
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.    
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)       
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)       
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)       
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)       
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)       
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)       
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)       
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()       
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlConnection.<Open>b__7()       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)       
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlConnection.<Open>b__6()       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)       
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)       
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlConnection.Open(RetryPolicy retryPolicy)       
   at NHibernate.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlDbConnection.Open()       
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()       
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()       
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection()       
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)       
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---       
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)       
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)       
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.RequireNew(IsolationLevel level)       
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.RequireNew()       
   at Orchard.Tasks.BackgroundService.Sweep()
```

Also, we have a follow up question here: [Site down: error log pattern of login failure x20, then invalid object name x20, then again login failure x20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538086/site-down-error-log-pattern-of-login-failure-x20-then-invalid-object-name-x20)

Comment: There a lots of possible cases - hard to tell. It might be that some erroneous connection data was still cached within the app (when backup resore happened), connection pool got exhausted etc.

Comment: It turns out the invalid login errors happened before restoring the database from the backup. After analyzing the logs, we saw the following pattern. About twenty "login failed" errors, followed by about twenty "invalid object name" errors, followed again by about twenty more "login failed" errors.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases connection pooling problems are related to "connection leaks." Your application probably doesn't close its database connections correctly and consistently.
SQL Server allows a maximum of 32767 connections by default.
After restarting the Application Pool you have drop all connections.